# Off Diagonal Zero Entries in Pure State Density Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Let 
$$\rvert\psi\rangle = a_u\rvert u\rangle + a_d\rvert d\rangle = \langle u\rvert\psi\rangle | u\rangle + \langle d\rvert \psi\rangle |d\rangle,$$
where
$$\rvert u\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 0  \\ \end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad\rvert d\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then 
$$\rvert\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} a_u \\ a_d \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \langle u\rvert\psi\rangle \\ \langle d\rvert\psi\rangle \\ \end{pmatrix},
\quad\text{and}\quad
\langle\psi\rvert = \begin{pmatrix} \bar a_u & \bar a_d \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \langle\psi\rvert u\rangle & \langle\psi\rvert d\rangle \\ \end{pmatrix},$$
so the density matrix corresponding to $|\psi\rangle$ is given by
\begin{align}
\rvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert 
&= \begin{pmatrix} \langle u\rvert\psi\rangle \\ \langle d\rvert\psi\rangle \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \langle\psi\rvert u\rangle & \langle\psi\rvert d\rangle \\ \end{pmatrix}
\\&  = \begin{pmatrix} \langle u\rvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert u\rangle & \langle u\rvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert d\rangle \\ \langle d\rvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert u\rangle & \langle d\rvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert d\rangle \end{pmatrix} 
\\ & = \begin{pmatrix} a_u\bar a_u & \color{blue}{a_u \bar a_d} \\ \color{blue}{a_d \bar a_u} & a_d \bar a_d \end{pmatrix} 
\\& = \begin{pmatrix} \rvert a_u\rvert^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \rvert a_d\rvert^2\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

How do you show that the off diagonal terms $\color{blue}{a_u\bar a_d}$ and $\color{blue}{a_d\bar a_u}$ come out to 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those terms are only zero if one of $a_u$ or $a_d$ is zero, i.e. if $|\psi\rangle$ coincides with one of the basis vectors. The off-diagonal terms of a density matrix are known as its *coherences* and they are one of the most important parts of the matrix. (The diagonal terms, on the other hand, are known as populations.)

For a pure state that's not a basis state, in general, the coherences will not vanish. You *can* make them vanish by considering a mixed state, which has the form
$$
\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|,
$$
where the $p_i$ are nonnegative weights that sum to one. In that case, the coherences will typically be smaller than for a pure state with the same populations, and in some special cases they can vanish completely.

For a pure state, though, this won't happen.